# Binding data into view - Is it better to pass data down from parent views to child/grandchild views or initialize/query data whenever creating views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, binding, frontend, marionette

I am working on a Backbone/Marionette project. This project implements a way to cache data on local memory after loading them from server. Therefore data can be access anytime, anywhere within the project.

This makes me wonder what is the better way to populate data to view in my case:

```
const ChildView = marionette.View.extend({/*...*/});

const ParentView = marionette.View.extend({
  // ...
  onRender() {

    // 1: pass data to child view from parent view
    const childView = new ChildView({
      data: this.options.data,
    }));

    // 2: initialize data when creating new child view
    const childView = new ChildView({
      data: SomeModel.new({/* some properties */}),
    }));
  },
  // ...
});

new ParentView({
    data: SomeModel.new({/* some properties */}),
}).render();
```

Both methods work correctly. However, the project view structure is pretty deep and complicated so I prefer the second way because with the first one I would need to go up and down a lot to check what `data` is and where it comes from.

Do you think if there are any possible problems with this method?

Comment: What is `SomeModel.new`? what does it do?

Comment: @TJ `SomeModel.new` creates a new instance of collection/model. If `SomeModel.new` is called and populated with data previously, all preceding `SomeModel.new` with same properties will return collection/model with same data

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the 1st way, passing data from parent to child, but it depends on what your views are doing.

For me, a big advantage of sharing a data object is that updating it within one view updates it in all other views (this will work if you pass an existing backbone Model, or any object as `data`). This can save a lot of work... when a user updates their background color (for example), you can update it *once* in your `BackgroundColorChoose` view, and know that it is already updated everywhere else that data is in use.

In a sense, it doesn't matter where the data came from, only what it represents (because it can be accessed/modified from within any of your views).

I can imagine scenarios where this approach is not good, but I've found it makes a good baseline to start from (and avoids the need to trust browser-caching)

Comment: In my project, `SomeModel.new` actually returns a Backbone model/collection of the same data. The returned models/collections are also kept in sync with each others and server too, therefore both binding method works correctly

Comment: Sounds like which method may not be a huge difference. I still sort of prefer passing data that is readily available rather than being a bit less direct, invoking caching magic. But if there were reasons to do it the other way, sounds like it makes no big difference.

Comment: Passing data works fine, actually that's how most of my teammates are doing it. The thing is I find myself passing them down too many times, because my view structure is really deep now, and some views don't event use the data just need to pass them down